# First setOutline color statement works the second gives syntax error?

Tags: python

I have verified that startTime is a legitimate string. The Text Point line does not give and error but the setOutline color gives and error for the Start Time Text. The second Text was copied from the first and only the name and position values changed. The lines look identical except for the name. I tried with and w/o the startTime string and w/o the commented out print line.

```
 labelX = Text(Point(700, 675), "TIME")                      # Label X Axis
 labelX.setOutline(color_rgb(0,255,255))     
 labelX.draw(win)

 result=getTime()                           # Put Start Time on Graph
 startTime = result[1]
 # print(startTime)
 labelStart = Text(Point(60,60,"Start Time:"startTime)
 labelStart.setOutline(color_rgb(0,255,255))    # Syntax Error  
 labelStart.draw(win)
```

I get the same invalid syntax error with the string, startTime removed from labelStart and with result, startTime=, and print line completely removed.

Comment: You didn't close the parentheses on your `labelStart = Text(Point(60,60,"Start Time:"startTime)` line (specifically, your `Point()` is not closed properly) - count opened vs closed parentheses to see the error. Also, you cannot concat strings like that, add `+` between `"Start Time:"` and `startTime`.

Comment: Thanks Maybe it was just midnight programming blues. Sure baffled me though. That line is now: :labelStart = Text(Point(150,30),"Start Time: "+startTime). Had to juggle position a little to put it where I wanted on the screen.